# Change Connection datasource path for Tabular databse

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssas-tabular

I am trying to change Connection Datasource Path for MSSQL 2017.
My code:

```
$ServerName="localhost\olap17"
$loadInfo = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")

$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
 break
}
foreach ($dbase in $server.Databases )
{
Write-Output ( "Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB; Data Sources: {3} " -f $dbase.Name, $dbase.State, ($dbase.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"), $dbase.Model.DataSources.Count )
foreach ($dsource in $dbase.Model.DataSources)
{
    $dsource.ConnectionDetails.Address.Path = $dsource.ConnectionDetails.Address.Path.Replace('OLDSERVER', 'NEWSERVER')
    echo ">>> Datasource: " $dsource.ConnectionDetails.ToString()
}
}
```

Output appears correct, but when I check out Connection properties, I see path unchanged:

```
Database: Billing Cycle Delivery; Status: Unprocessed; Size: 0MB; Data Sources: 5 
Datasource: 
{
"protocol": "file",
"address": {
"path": "\\\\NEWSERVER\\Telco\\Models\\Billing Cycle Delivery\\Data Sources\\Billing.xlsx"
},
"authentication": null,
"query": null
}
```

Looking like new properties not passed back to server...
Where is my problem? I can't find any useful information on the Internet :(

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: See here for how to generate a TMSL ALTER command to change your data source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e7fb92d3-ceba-4fe6-95c0-6cb57d43153d/how-to-set-data-source-for-ssas-project-for-seamless-deployment-to-production?forum=sqlanalysisservices. See here for how to run this TSML in powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models-scripting-language-commands/alter-command-tmsl?view=sql-server-2017. When you've worked it all out, _please_ write up your answer and post it here.

Comment: I just double checked the DataSource documentation on MSDN, but I couldn't find a `ConnectionDetails` property for that object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.datasource?. view=sqlserver-2016&viewFallbackFrom=sqlserver-2017#properties . I would double check that what you're treating like a string is a string and/or you don't need to call a `Refresh()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Needed:

```
$dbase.Update(1)
```

This is required to push changes to the server.

My final script, if somebody needs:

```
$changeSource = 'OLDSERVER'
$changeTarget = 'NEWSERVER'
$ServerName="localhost\olap17"
$loadInfo = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($ServerName)
if ($server.name -eq $null) {
 Write-Output ("Server '{0}' not found" -f $ServerName)
 break
}
foreach ($dbase in $server.Databases )
{
 Write-Output ( "Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB; Data Sources: {3} " -f $dbase.Name, $dbase.State, ($dbase.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"), $dbase.Model.DataSources.Count )
 foreach ($dsource in $dbase.Model.DataSources)
 {
    $dsource.ConnectionDetails.Address.Path = $dsource.ConnectionDetails.Address.Path.Replace($changeSource, $changeTarget)
    echo ">>> Datasource name: " $dsource.Name " Connection: " $dsource.ConnectionDetails.ToString()
    $dbase.Update(1)
}
}
$server.Disconnect($ServerName)
echo "Connection closed"
echo "------------- Confirmation --------------"
$server.connect($ServerName)
foreach ($dbase in $server.Databases )
{
 Write-Output ( "Database: {0}; Status: {1}; Size: {2}MB; Data Sources: {3} " -f $dbase.Name, $dbase.State, ($dbase.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"), $dbase.Model.DataSources.Count )
 foreach ($newds in $dbase.Model.DataSources)
 {
    echo ">>> Datasource name: " $newds.Name " Connection: " $newds.ConnectionDetails.ToString()
 }
}
$server.Disconnect($ServerName)
```

Here is MS article that help me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.database?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-2016